# Using androidannotations to fire an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-annotations

I have successfully used androidannotations @Extra to decode an intent and get the sent message as this snippet demonstrates:

```
@Extra(MyActivity.MESSAGE)
String intentMessage;

@ViewById(displayMessage)
TextView textView;

@AfterViews
protected void init() {
    textView.setText(intentMessage);
}
```

I'm missing how, if possible, to create the intent in the first place using annotations. e.g replace the following

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity_.class);
intent.putExtra(MESSAGE, s);
startActivity(intent);
```

with something. Is this possible? (I'm totally new to all this so probably am missing something terribly obvious)

SOLUTION:

```
DisplayMessageActivity_.intent(this).intentMessage(s).start();
```

Where intentMessage is the name of the extra field.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use the following:

```
// Starting the activity
MyListActivity_.intent(context).start();

// Building an intent from the activity
Intent intent = MyListActivity_.intent(context).get();

// You can provide flags
MyListActivity_.intent(context).flags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).start();

// You can even provide extras defined with @Extra in the activity
MyListActivity_.intent(context).myDateExtra(someDate).start();

// startActivityForResult() equivalent:
MyListActivity_.intent(context).startForResult();
```

Source: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/HowItWorks

Comment: Can you possibly hold my hand a little here because I'm not seeing it. I read this before but I'm missing how that addresses my issue of setting the extra for EXTRA_MESSAGE - this is just a list of APIs from which I dont see how I set the string associated with the extra name (EXTRA_MESSAGE above) and then to invoke StartActivity.

Comment: Sorry, I have actually not used the @Extra annotation, but am simply aware of its existence. I am glad that you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Possibly you could accept my answer below to close this up?

Comment: I cannot do that as I am not the asker. I believe you are :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution. Finally saw the pattern on how it works. Thanks.

```
DisplayMessageActivity_.intent(this).intentMessage(s).start();
```

where intentMessage is the @Extra defined in the activity to be started e.g

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_display)
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String MESSAGE = "net.richardriley.MyFirst.MESSAGE";

    @Extra(MESSAGE)
    String intentMessage;

    @ViewById(displayMessage)
    TextView textView;

    @AfterViews
    protected void init() {
        textView.setText(intentMessage);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but I have developed a library that does exactly this. It uses annotations to generate the intent code.

Check it out in here: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator